# LESS: Is there any syntax to access the value of a property in the current rule-set?

Tags: syntax, less

Is there any less syntax to access the value of a property in the current rule-set?  For example I want to set height to twice width without creating a variable:

```
.img {
  width:20px;
  height: ?width*2;  // dummy code.
}
```

Comment: That is not the "value of a rule", it's the "value of a property".

Comment: short answer: no :) you could do this with js (get the width, and multiply that by 2, and assign that value to the height), but I bet we can come up with some LESS-only solution. What are you trying to do / why don't you want to use a LESS variable?

Answer (score 2):

**Though may have easy solution, but you can solve it by using "em".
It depend on font-size not width/anything else, please see steps:**

- At first set required font-size against this div.
- For margin, padding, height, width properties use "em" instead of "px"
- calculation is:  1em = div's font size. (a)x(em)= (a)x(font-size).

> (font-size = 12px and width=1.5em (1.5em=1.5*12px or
>   18px) and height=3em (3em = 3*12px or 36px))

```
**For your case if font-size is 10px:**
    .foo{
      font-size: 10px;  //Let's think div's font size 10px
      width:2em;   //10*2 = 20px   that dynamically calculated
      height: 4em;  // 10*4 = 40px  that double of width
    }
```

Each and every time height will be double than width but problem is you have to use font-size  to change size with this ratio.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But the question is not looking for method of sizing text relatively.

Comment: Sorry @PHPst , actually i  failed to describe properly, once i have faced this problem, that because i have shared this trick.
**I have edited see it now.** Thanks

Comment: Thanks again. The question is: "Is there any **syntax** to access the **value** of a **property** in the current rule-set? Sorry, I forgot to refer to less in the question's body. The less is about less: css pre-proccessor.